# Is it OK to make some 3D art as CC0 or CC BY-SA if it contains a trademark/logo?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, trademark

If I create a 3D model that I want to distribute as CC0 or CC BY-SA but it contains a logo or trademark that I'm not the owner is it OK to do so?

Lets say for example that I make a 3D Coke can with the Coke logo, would it be OK to freely distribute it?

Answer (score 1):

### You can't license what you don't own!

Let's for a moment assume that you have a statue in your front lawn, made by some artist. You own the *physical* statue, but you don't own the *copyright*.

Because you don't own the copyright in the statue, you can't make a copy of it in any way or fashion.

Now, Trademark law only intermingles with copyright law where the trademark is *artistic*. Most logos for trademarks do manage to cross the very low bar of creativity needed to count as artistic, and thus carry a copyright in that design. For example, the Coke wave font is artistic lettering and not just utilitarian - and it is copyrightable. In fact, there are about **615** different artistic objects that are registered at the copyright office that contain the phrase Coca-Cola, including various T-shirts, commercials, and... Logo styles. Luckily the basic logo-text might be out of copyright, but it does not make any modern rendition or other addition free game.

But besides copyright infringement, using **more** than absolutely necessary when referring to a trademark is trademark infringement. When referring to a different company's trademark, you can't use their logos - plaintext is the only you can do to do *nominative use* of a trademark. You could have your own trademark in a different sector, but here it gets ugly: Coca-Cola is a **famous mark**. You can not use a famous mark even outside the area that the mark is registered in. Using Coca-Cola's logo font violates [15 U.S. Code § 1125(c)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/1125).

Since you do not own the design used, you can not give a license to what you don't own - you would need a license from Coca-Cola to distribute the model under that license - and they won't give you a CC0 or CC-By-Sa license for that.

Comment: We got an entirely different conclusion here. To my knowledge, text is not protected, the _font_ would be, but as software, not the letters written using it.

Comment: @PMF the *design* of the font, in that specific angle is an artwork that *just* manages to count as creative.

Comment: I've seen much more complex ones that where considered not creative enough so they could be hosted on Wikimedia Commons, though I guess this could be a lengthy debate between lawyers. However, since it was first used at least in 1923, it is now out of copyright anyway.

Comment: @PMF not in all renditions or combinations, but the real problem is Trademark - you can not use the trademark of another company **at all**

Comment: Do you have a source for that? IANAL, but apparently WMFs standpoint is different, otherwise they wouldn't allow uploading images of trademarked logos/items _for commercial use_.

Comment: @PMF 15 U.S. Code § 1125(c)

Comment: That section is about an attempt to use the logo (or one that looks similar) to sell your own goods. I don't think it applies if you are referring to the original owner of the trademark. A grocery store can use the Cola logo to advertise a discount on soft drinks, but they cannot use the logo to advertise on something that does not belong to the coca cola company.

Comment: The Coca Cola logo of, say, the 1890s would not be protected by copyright, however.

Comment: @Trish you can use the trademark of another company to denote the company or its products.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_use  for example, you're allowed to say "I like Pepsi better than Coke."

Comment: @PMF Sorry but it's still not clear for me. CC0 says that it doesn't include trademarks. Is it possible to use a CC0 license and exclude the logo copyright, so I could include the logo in the free CC0 material?

Comment: @user5507535 No, a CC-license (regardless of CC-0, CC-BY, or whatever) does not say _anything_ about trademarks. only about copyright. In my opinion, you can distribute and sell your cola bottle any way you like, as long as you're not claiming to be working for the Coca-Cola company.

Answer (score 1):

Trademark rights and copyright are generally distinct. Things can be protected by either or by both, but most of the time, only copyright is relevant for the possibility to distribute something under a CC-BY license. A trademark *can* be copyrighted, but that requires it to have a certain originality (the level of which depends by country).

The [Coca Cola Logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Coca-Cola_logo.svg) in particular is not protected by copyright for a variety of reasons:

- It is to simple, consisting of only text
- It has been created more than 95 years ago, so it's public domain in the US.

It's still trademarked as obviously the brand is in use, but as long as you're not trying to sell coke under the name of Coca-Cola you should be fine.

Comment: [Famous mark makes your "don'T sell coke" irrelevant](https://www.inta.org/topics/famous-well-known-marks/) - ANY infringement on any market on a famous mark is prohibited.

Comment: @Trish any infringement may be prohibited, but why would you think that "don't sell Coke" is infringement?